# How do I block the sale of a token after it has been purchased?

Tags: solidity

I wrote a token on ethereum. Now I don't know how to block the sale of the token on the marketplace until a certain point. Tell me what feature to add so that users can't sell their token after purchase until a certain point. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way to do this is simply to set a time limit on the transfer function of the token, every erc20, erc721 has a transfer and also transferfrom  function that allows them to move token

```
uint256 time = 12 weeks;
function transfer(//params){
  require(block.timestamp > time);
  // rest of the code
}

function transferFrom(//params){
  require(block.timestamp > time);
  // rest of the code
}
```

note:This example is for the whole token user at this point until the 12 weeks no user can transfer tokens, it's is different from blacklisting some users from transferring tokens

Comment: Bruh, can you do more function?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, once you have purchased tokens, you cannot block their sale. You can only attempt to limit their sale by setting a maximum number of tokens that can be bought. You can set a maximum number of tokens that can be bought by adding a function in the smart contract code. The code should set a maximum limit for the total number of tokens that can be purchased, and then check if the token buyer has exceeded that limit. If the limit is exceeded, then the token sale should be blocked.